# I am building an LFS system for the first time. Should the Grub Bios Partition be primary or extended?

Tags: partition, lfs

I'd assume it would be primary, but I'd prefer to be sure before beginning.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems pretty opinion-based. I personally use primary partitions whenever I can when I'm using MBR.

Comment: If you can use gpt, I suggest you do. I have used it with BIOS and bios_grub partition starting in 2010. And then UEFI since about 2014. GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reference I can find to a "Grub Bios Partition" in LFS is mentioned [here](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/10.1/chapter02/creatingpartition.html):

> If the boot disk has been partitioned with a GUID Partition Table (GPT), then a small, typically 1 MB, partition must be created if it does not already exist.

You don't have [extended partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) in [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) as extended partitions are a feature of MBR partition tables.  So if you are offered an option to make the partition primary or extended, your disk currently has an MBR partition table not a GPT one.

You can start a new GPT partition table, completely reformatting your disk `/dev/sdb`, with:

```
cfdisk --zero /dev/sdb
```

If you intended to use MBR and not GPT then you don't need this partition as MBR already reserves this for the boot loader.  GPT on the other hand is more commonly used with [EFI boot](https://lfs-support.linuxfromscratch.narkive.com/QL1vP6qr/booting-lfs-and-uefi) and doesn't have this space reserved for a legacy boot loader.